# Node express specific IP router

Tags: node.js, express

I've been having this problem with nodejs express. Although it's working, I wanted to do something that I'm not sure if possible.

I'm hosting an express app on my localhost. My local server is also running hostapd. I have a hotspot.

Now the problem. I have this code.

```
app.use('/', portal);
app.use('/admin', passport.login , admin);
```

So I can visit `localhost:3000` and `localhost:3000/admin` just fine. They both show what I wanted. Question now is, is there a way to interchange this two when using the IP of the hotspot?

For example:

when visiting from hotspot, using an IP (example `http://10.0.0.1` and `http://10.0.0.1/admin`) I want to serve the app as is:

```
app.use('/', portal);
app.use('/admin', passport.login , admin);
```

but when visiting using localhost, I want to exchange the two or better yet remove the portal and go directly on admin:

```
app.use('/', passport.login , admin);
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply redirect your request from the portal to the admin if the current ip is 127.0.0.1 :

```
function redirectIfLocalhost(req, res, next) {
    // https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.ip
    if (req.ip === "127.0.0.1") {
        res.redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

app.use('/',redirectIfLocalhost , portal)
```

Nevertheless, I don't really know if it could be a security breach.

EDIT :

If i understand well, you want more something like this :

```
// Handle passeport login inside handleAdmin middleware
// But replace the next function to control the next middleware
function handleAdmin(req, res, next) {
    passeport.login(req, res, (route) => {
        if (route) next(route)
        else admin(req, res, next);
    });
}

function handlePortal(req, res, next) {
    if (req.ip === "127.0.0.1") {
        handleAdmin(req, res, next);
    } else {
        portal(req, res, next);
    }
}

function preventIfLocalhost(req, res, next) {
    if (req.ip === '127.0.0.1') {
        res.status(404).send() // To be completed or replaced
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

app.use('/', handlePortal);

app.use('/admin', preventIfLocalhost, handleAdmin);
```

I didn't try my code so small fixes may be necessary

Comment: yes that should work... but that's not the goal... I wanted to remove the "admin" endpoint when visiting localhost but still show the content of what the "admin" endpoint

Comment: If you programmatically remove the `/` endpoint, you will not be able to contact the portal endpoint from any route. More, remove route/middleware in express is not built-in neither easy

Answer (score 0):

you can get the ip from request or ip module and  create a new middleware to handle the request

```js
const ip = require('ip')

app.use('/',handleRedirection, admin);

function handleRedirection(req, res, next) {
  ip.address()==='127.0.0.1' || ip.isEqual('::1', '::0:1') ? next() : passport.login(req, res, next);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip... I'm into something like `app.use('/', portal, passport.login, admin);` now... I'm pretty sure I'm close

Comment: must be app.use('/',[ portal, passport.login], admin); you can pass an array of middlewares.

Comment: ahh nice to know... I will try this.. do you happen to know I could do it? either `portal` or `passport.login, admin` but not all three of them to run...

Comment: see if this helps https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-conditional-tree-middleware